# Use multiple conditions for count in terraform ternary operations using elseif

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code, hcl

I am trying to get terraform to create a resouce based on the count conditon as below, i cant get my head around the syntax, it should be something like below:

```
count = “${var.size[terraform.workspace] == "big" ? && local.ips[terraform.workspace] != “<none>“} then 10
elseif
${var.size[terraform.workspace] == "small"  && local.ips[terraform.workspace] != “<none>” } then 20
else 0
```

Comment: You have to use ternaries: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Comment: I know, I just can't understand how to do this with my conditions. @MattSchuchard

Answer (score 1):

Test below,

```tf
count = "${lookup(var.size, terraform.workspace, "None") == "big" && lookup(local.ips, terraform.workspace, "None") != "None" ? 10 : lookup(var.size, terraform.workspace, "None") == "small" && lookup(local.ips, terraform.workspace, "None") != "None" ? 20 : 0}"
```

Comment: Ty, will try this.